# Modify a value comparing two json

Tags: javascript, python, json, jq

I´ve a JSON data which is a array of dictionaries with the next syntax:

**file1.json**

```
[ 
     {

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 29, 2017 15:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "France",
     "Id": "123456",
     "Car": "Ferrari"

}

]
```

And I've another JSON data with similar syntax EXCEPT the field of **Date_and_Time**.

**file2.json**

```
[ 
{
  "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Age": "1",
    "Country": "France",
     "Id": "123456",
     "Car": "Ferrari"
},
{
    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "Germany",
     "Id": "2468",
     "Genre": "Male"

}
]
```

Both JSON data have the same number of Date_and_Time fields. What I want to do is to rewrite only the value of the first json for the value of the second json for the Date_and_Time

Expected output: **file3.json**

```
[ 
     {

    "Date_and_Time": "Dec 31, 2017 17:35:37",
    "Componente": "Bar",
    "Country": "Brazil",
    "Age": "3"

},

{

    "Date_and_Time": "Mar 31, 2018 14:35:37",
    "Componente": "Foo",
    "Country": "France",
     "Id": "123456",
     "Car": "Ferrari"

}

]
```

I dont have preference about what to use as long as it works. I have thought using jq but it didn't work because of this:

```
jq -n --argjson oldvals "$(< file1.json)" --argjson newvals "$(< file2.json)" '    reduce range($oldvals | length) as $idx      ($oldvals; .[$idx].Date_and_Time = $newvals[$idx].Date_and_Time)' > file3.json
```

it got the next message

`/usr/bin/jq: the list of argument is too long`

Comment: Can you be a little bit clear on how you are getting file3?

Comment: Passing file content as a command line argument is not a good idea at all. Adjust the JQ program to read files from the disk instead. `jq 'input as $in | reduce range(length) as $i (.; .[$i].Date_and_Time = $in[$i].Date_and_Time)' f1 f2`

Comment: @oguzismail - please add this as an answer so it can potentially be accepted.

Comment: @peak gotta sleep, you post it if you feel like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here with his permission is @oguzismail's excellent answer:

```
jq '
  input as $in
  | reduce range(length) as $i (.;
      .[$i].Date_and_Time = $in[$i].Date_and_Time)
' f1 f2
```

The important point is that the -s slurp command-line option can be easily avoided, as it should be whenever possible if efficiency is a consideration.

The above formulation, however, is a tiny bit subtle as it depends on the somewhat non-obvious fact that when `input` is used without the -n command-line option, it evaluates to the *second* JSON entity presented as input.  In the present case, that would be the JSON entity in f2; the top-level `.` by contrast evaluates to the JSON entity in f1.

So here's an alternative and perhaps more intuitive presentation of much the same program:

```
jq -n '
  input as $f2
  | input
  | reduce range(length) as $i (.;
      .[$i].Date_and_Time = $f2[$i].Date_and_Time)
' f2 f1
```

Comment: Re "*The important point is that the -s slurp command-line option can be easily avoided*", You say that, but your snippets slurp both files. You may not have used `-s`, but you still loaded both files into memory before doing anything. That said, I'll concede that if `f2` was a stream rather than an array, it wouldn't be slurped by your first version. `f1` requires slurping by both snippets, though

Comment: Re "*as it should be whenever possible if efficiency is a consideration.*", It so weird to use "efficiency" to refer to memory usage without clarification. It's not wrong, but it sure is confusing.

Comment: Reading a bunch of files is not the same as slurping them: the latter involves creating an additional
array.
Consider e.g. the trace output produced by:
`echo 1 2 | jq --debug-trace -s .[]` and `echo 1 2 | jq --debug-trace .`
Although the main inefficiency is typically related to memory,
there is typically also a time inefficiency, though whether it is significant of course depends
on the particulars.

Comment: You might like to study the differences between the output produced by
`echo 1 2 | jq --debug-trace -s '. as $x | [$x[0], $x[1]] | length'`
vs
`echo 1 2 | jq --debug-trace -n '[input,input] | length'`

Comment: The point is that you were claiming you were avoiding the problems of `-s`, while that's not completely untrue. You create an array with the entirety of the file, which is exactly the reason to avoid `-s`.

Answer (score 0):

supposed You´ve already have the data into those arrays json1, json2 and will build json3

```
const json3 = json1.map( 
    ( element, index) => { 
          const newData =  json2[index]
          return { 
           ...element , 
           "Date_and_Time" : newData["Date_and_Time"] ,
           } 
          }
     )
```

Give it a look [here](https://repl.it/join/ycgdafnn-bokomoko)

Answer (score 0):

A python version, that also loads and writes files

```
import json

file1 = json.loads(open("file1.json").read())
file2 = json.loads(open("file2.json").read())

def change_field(a,b,f):
  a[f]=b[f]
  return a

file3 = list(map(lambda x: change_field(x[1],file2[x[0]],"Date_and_Time"), enumerate(file1)))

with open("file3.json","wt") as f:
  f.write(json.dumps(file3, indent=4))
```

Answer (score 0):

jq version summary:

It is basically all there except for the file input part.

```
$ jq -s '.[0] as $oldvals
         |.[1] as $newvals
         |reduce range($oldvals|length) as $idx
         (
           $oldvals;
           .[$idx].Date_and_Time = $newvals[$idx].Date_and_Time
         )' file1.json file2.json > file3.json
```

Comment: It would be far better to avoid using the -s option! See e.g. @oguzmail’s contribution on this page.